# Conditional Styles in Oracle APEX 4.2

Tags: css, sql, oracle-apex

I'm using APEX 4.2 to build a Training Calendar for the organization I support at work. I am by no means an DBA or any kind of programming expert. I've been learning a lot through trial and error.

My calendar is built, but what I am trying to do is change how items display based on a column in my table. For instance, I have two project types: Project A and Project B. I would like these to have a different border color on my calendar display. Currently, I am using the below CSS code but this applies to all events:

```html
<style>
.Day a, .NonDay a, .Today a, .WeekendDay a {
    font: normal 10px/12px Arial,sans-serif !important;
    padding: 2px !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border: 1px solid #FF1414;
}

.Day a:hover, .NonDay a:hover, .Today a:hover, .WeekendDay a:hover {
    background-color: #A3A3A3;
    border: 1px solid #FF1414;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
```

I want to be able to alter this so that when PROJECT = A a certain style like above is applied, and when PROJECT = B a variation of the above style is applied.

Does anyone have any guidance on how I can do this? I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks you,
Christina

Comment: Can you please show the resulting HTML code and serverside code, if any exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know APEX, but what you need is to extend html elements (whatever it is, could be a `<li/>`, a `<td/>` or something else) with project-specific css classes. You did not show your HTML code, so I just guess the calendar is build with a table. If so, this could look like:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="NonDay"><a href="#">27</a></td>
        <td class="NonDay"><a href="#">28</a></td>
        <td class="NonDay"><a href="#">29</a></td>
        <td class="NonDay"><a href="#">30</a></td>
        <td class="NonDay"><a href="#">31</a></td>
        <td class="Day WeekendDay"><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td class="Day WeekendDay"><a href="#">2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Day"><a href="#">3</a></td>
        <td class="Day"><a href="#">4</a></td>
        <td class="Day ProjectA"><a href="#">5</a></td> <!-- see the class -->
        <td class="Day ProjectB"><a href="#">6</a></td> <!-- see the class -->
        <td class="Day"><a href="#">7</a></td>
        <td class="Day WeekendDay Today"><a href="#">8</a></td>
        <td class="Day WeekendDay"><a href="#">9</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this, you can style this classes like you did for the other classes:

```css
.ProjectA a {
    border-color: blue;
}

.ProjectB a {
    border-color: red;
}
```

The question I can't answer is how to add css classes in APEX, but this question would better fit to oracles support forums or maybe to https://superuser.com/ because it's not a programming related question.

Comment: The question is very much related to programming in APEX!

Comment: ...But I agree that also asking in the APEX topic on forums.oracle.com would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. You have given me some things to think about. My biggest challenge is that this is not my area of expertise, so I feel like I'm learning APEX, SQL and CSS all at once. It's a bit overwhelming. Also, I did post to the Oracle forums and got very little help there.

Answer (score 1):

I have a table that assigns colors to the different projects, so when I pull the event from the calendar table, I join it to the project table and grab  the color.

SELECT e.ID, '**'||DESCRIPTION||'**' DESCRIPTION, event_date FROM EVENTS e, project a
where e.project_id=a.project_id;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the individual calendar entries you could apply a class in the SELECT statement like this:

```
select ..., 
       '<div class=project"' || project || '>' || description || '</div>'
             as description
from ...
```

This would result in HTML for the entries like:

```
<div class="projectA">This is project A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL code add column PROJECT_TYPE returning type of your project.
In calendar properties change "Display Type" to "Custom".
in "Column Format" input something like

```
 <span class="#PROJECT_TYPE#">#COLUMN_VALUE#</span>
```

Then define ProjectA style.